# How to access and standardize cell array elements (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, mean

I have a cell array data structure and I want to standardize the elements of it. How can I apply the `zscore` or the mean and std to each cell array? I tried doing the following but it is incorrect. The code below randomly generates 50 different sets of data each of 1000 elements.   I even tried the following `cellfun(@(x)(x-mu)./sg,X,'UniformOutput',false)` but I cannot compute the `mu` (mean) and `sg` (standard deviation) for the cell structure. Please help.

```
for n  = 1: 50

   x=rand(1,1000);

    X(n)=  {x} ;


end

XV = zscore(X);
```

Comment: Can’t you call `zscore` within the loop?

Comment: `zscore` should be for a vector. So, are you suggesting that I normalize the data `x` and then pass it into the cell structure `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zscore` is a function in the Statistics Toolbox, which I don't have. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html) says that you can apply it to standardize a matrix using the `'all'` option (**note!** this is new to MATLAB R2018b):

```
zscore(X,0,'all'); % won't work in versions of MATLAB before R2018b
```

If, like me, you don't have this toolbox, it should be equivalent to:

```
(X - mean(X(:))) / std(X(:));
```

So we can write an anonymous function like this:

```
standardize = @(X)(X - mean(X(:))) / std(X(:));
```

or equivalently

```
standardize = @(X)zscore(X,0,'all');
```

Now, you can apply this function to all matrices in an array using `cellfun`:

```
X = cell(5,3);
for ii=1:numel(X)
  X{ii} = rand(1,1000);
end
XV = cellfun(standardize,X,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both the options. The anonymous function option works however, the `zscore` option: `standardize = @(X)zscore(X,0,'all');` throws error `Error using sum
Invalid option. Option must be 'double', 'native', 'default', 'omitnan' or 'includenan'.

Error in mean (line 116)
        y = sum(x, dim, flag) ./ size(x,dim);

Error in zscore (line 43)
mu = mean(x,dim);`   Is it because my cell array structure is different? I have 100 different sets of one dimensional data. Each one dimensional data is of 1000 samples in length. So, `X` is `1x100` cell array structure.

Comment: I pass the data to `X` inside the `for loop` as shown in my question which is different than the syntax that you have written in your answer. Is the error due to the mismatch in the way the cell structure is defined? I am using R2018

Comment: @RiaGeorge: I don't have the `zscore` function, so I was going off the documentation. It seems that the `'all'` mode is new to R2018b, sorry for that.

Comment: @RiaGeorge: your way of defining the cell struct is equivalent, it is just a preference of mine to do it this other way. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I can use the other first option eventhough `zscore` is not working. That is fine.  thank you very much.